# Algolia Geo Search not seeing ranking info

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm trying to set up a working geo seach with Algolia.

So far I'm stunned how easy it was to set up. The next thing I'm trying to implement is to show the distance from the found object to the user-selected location.

I'm using instantsearch.js with places.js.

This is my set up for instantsearch:

```
let search = instantsearch({
    appId: 'appid',
    apiKey: 'apikey',
    indexName: 'dev_index',
    url_sync: true,
    searchFunction: function(helper) {
        helper.setQueryParameter('getRankingInfo', 1).search();
    }
});
```

And the places widget (it's called different than in the documentation because I'm pulling it in via NPM)

```
search.addWidget(
    placesWidget({
        container: '#places-box',
        type: 'city',
        aroundLatLngViaIP: false,
        countries: 'de'
    })
);
```

If I look into the dev tools, I see the following query parameters after selecting a town in the places.js widget:

[image]

But my hits object doesn't contain the expected "_rankingInfo" object:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helper` passed to `searchFunction` is not able to set additional query parameters.

To make it work you can use it like this:

```
searchFunction: function(helper) {
    this.helper.setQueryParameter('getRankingInfo', true);

    helper.search();
}
```

It'll do the trick.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ur6qetp1/

Comment: Thanks a ton!
Do you happen to know in which unit the distance is given back?

Comment: @Tim It's in meters - https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/geo-search/geo-search-overview#display-the-distance

Comment: If you know where to look, it's easy, thanks again :)